# Unable to set max and min range in datepicker based on two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have three input types where which all are associated with date picker
[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shoaibista/X2BFT/)

```
   <div class="demo"> 

   <label for="from">From</label> 
   <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> 
   <label for="to">to</label> 
   <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/> 

   <label for="resultant">Resultant</label>
   <input type="text" id="resultant">
   </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $(function() {
       $("#from").datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 3,
          onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
           this.focus();
          }
    });

        $("#to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            this.focus();

        }
    });

        $("#resultant").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {   
         $('#resultant').datepicker("option","minDate",$('#from').datepicker('getDate')); 
         $('#resultant').datepicker("option","maxDate",$('#to').datepicker('getDate')); 

        }
    });
});
```

Issue here is when I selected resultant date input box for first time, minRange and maxRange are not selected. Second time they are selected. The reason for this is min and max range are set after selecting for first time

How I can get rid of that?

UPDATE: After following one of the approach,I am getting this UI[image]
But the year field is not seen. Any reason for that??

Comment: Can't you do like until user has not selected the from and to date make he selected input box as disable

Comment: Why dont you disabled the resultant till user set min and max dates

Comment: No we can't do that.Can't change project requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below javascript code for range fix

```
  $("#resultant").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            beforeShow: changeRange,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                //$('#resultant').datepicker("option", "minDate", $('#from').datepicker('getDate'));
                //$('#resultant').datepicker("option", "maxDate", $('#to').datepicker('getDate'));
            }
        });

        function changeRange(input) {
            if ($('#from').val() != null && $('#to').val() != null) {
                var minDate = new Date($('#from').val());
                var maxDate = new Date($('#to').val());
                //minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1)

                return {
                    minDate: minDate,
                    maxDate: maxDate
                };
            }

            return {};
        }
```

Comment: Please see the updated question and can u tell me why year is not seen?? Before it was seen.

Comment: In your fiddle example, year getting display

Comment: Yupe, fiddle doesn't have problem. Just wanted to ask that do you have any idea that why year hides.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "onSelect" for "from" and "to", not for "resultant".
Right now, boundary calculation takes place *after* picking date in "resultant".

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#resultant').datepicker("option", "minDate", $('#from').datepicker('getDate'));
            this.focus();

        }
    });

    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#resultant').datepicker("option", "maxDate", $('#to').datepicker('getDate'));
            this.focus();

        }
    });

    $("#resultant").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            this.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found

```
  <label for="resultant">Resultant</label>
  <input type="text" id="resultant" onclick="showDatePicker()">
```

**JavaScript code**

```
 function showDatePicker(){
   //check null safe too
     $('#resultant').datepicker("show");
     $('#resultant').datepicker("option","minDate",$('#from').datepicker('getDate')); 
     $('#resultant').datepicker("option","maxDate",$('#to').datepicker('getDate')); 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because onSelect doesn't fire until you've selected something or put text into the `input` of the `datepicker` what you want to do is set the min and max date in the onClose of the from and to `datepicker`

working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X2BFT/2/)

```
$(function () {
     $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            this.focus();

        },
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {            
            $('#resultant').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            this.focus();

        },
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#resultant').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $("#resultant").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3       
    });    
});
```